# What is failing in this HTML (won't display)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The only thing I get when I run this HMTL/jQuery/CSS is the forestgreen background. The referenced plugin (gomap.js) is in the same directory, so it should have no trouble finding it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Some Unsolved Murders in the U.S., 1953 - 2013</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script src="gomap.js"></script> 
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;;
    background-color:forestgreen;
}
#map { 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
} 
h1 {
color: forestgreen;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: 'Century Gothic', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
p {
color: darkorange;
font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', Consolas, Candara, sans-serif;
}
.away {
color: black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#map").goMap({ 
        latitude: 36.25,  
        longitude: -100, 
        maptype: 'ROADMAP',
        zoom: 5
    }); 

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'La Crosse, Wisconsin',
title: 'Evelyn Hartley',
html: '<h1>Evelyn Hartley</h1><h2>La Crosse, Wisconsin</h2><h2>October 24, 1953</h2><h2>Age: 15</h2><p>Evelyn Hartley was babysitting for Professor Viggo Rasmusen on the evening of October 24, 1953 when she was kidnapped. That was the night of the La Crosse football game and attendance was high. There were signs of a struggle in the living room where her broken glasses were left. In the basement there was blood and an open window where the kidnapper came in and took Evelyn out. Though her body was never found, weeks later bloody undergarments resembling hers were discovered on Highway 14, two miles south of La Crosse. There was a fifteen-minute window between the Rasmusens''s leaving and her disappearance.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Bay Village, Ohio',
title: 'Marilyn Reese Sheppard',
html: '<h1>Marilyn Reese Sheppard</h1><h2>Bay Village, Ohio</h2><h2>July 4, 1954</h2><h2>Age: 31</h2><p>Marilyn Reese Sheppard, wife of Sam Sheppard, attacked and killed in her home in Bay Village, Ohio, United States, on 4 July 1954. Sam Sheppard was later convicted of killing his pregnant wife, but this was overturned in 1966, and he was acquitted in a new trial. He claimed his wife was killed by a bushy-haired man who also attacked him and knocked him unconscious twice. Their son slept through the night, just down the hall from the bedroom in which his mother was murdered. The trial of Sam Sheppard received extensive publicity and was called "carnival atmosphere" by the U.S. Supreme Court.[20] The Sheppard case was a large part of the inspiration for the television series and later movie The Fugitive.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Chicago, Illinois',
title: 'Barbara and Patricia Grimes',
html: '<h1>Barbara and Patricia Grimes</h1><h2>Chicago, Illinois</h2><h2>December 28, 1956</h2><h2>Age: 13</h2><p>Barbara and Patricia Grimes disappeared on 28 December 1956, in Chicago, Illinois after going to a cinema to watch an Elvis Presley movie. Their disappearance launched one of the biggest missing-persons hunts in Chicago history. However, police were not able to determine what happened to the Grimes sisters. On January 22, 1957 their naked bodies were found off a road near Willow Springs, Illinois. The corpses contained various bruises and marks (for example puncture wounds in the chest that may have come from an ice pick) that were never fully explained.</p>'
});


$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Philadelphia, Pennsylvania',
title: 'Boy in the Box',
html: '<h1>&qt;Boy in the Box&qt;</h1><h2>Philadelphia, Pennsylvania</h2><h2>February 25, 1957</h2><h2>Age: 4-6</h2><p>Boy in the Box, sometimes known as "America''s Unknown Child" is a name given to an unidentified murder victim, approximately 4 to 6 years old. The body of the boy was found battered and naked inside a cardboard box on 25 February 1957 in Philadelphia, Pennsylvania. The case received massive media attention and pictures of the boy were placed in every gas bill in Philadelphia. It has been featured on the America''s Most Wanted television series, but despite all attention the case remains unsolved and the boy''s identity unknown.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'El Monte, California',
title: 'Geneva (Jean) Hilliker Ellroy',
html: '<h1>Geneva (Jean) Hilliker Ellroy</h1><h2>El Monte, California</h2><h2>June 22, 1958</h2><h2>Age: 43</h2><p>Geneva (Jean) Hilliker Ellroy, a 43-year-old divorced nurse, was found strangled to death near Arroyo High School in El Monte, California on 22 June 1958. No promising suspects were ever produced, though she was seen with an unknown man and woman in the hours before her death. The case received only superficial notice from the media, possibly due to the recent homicide of Johnny Stompanato. The victim''s ten-year-old son James Ellroy, (then Lee Earle Ellroy), would become a bestselling crime novelist later in life and would revisit his mother''s murder in his 1996 memoir, My Dark Places.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Washington, D.C.',
title: 'Mary Meyer',
html: '<h1>Mary Meyer</h1><h2>Washington, D.C.</h2><h2>October 12, 1964</h2><h2>Age: 43</h2><p>Mary Meyer, a socialite from Washington, D.C., and close friend of U.S. President John F. Kennedy.[26] Shot to death on 12 October 1964 by an unknown assailant after finishing a painting and going for a walk. She was heard screaming for help by a mechanic on a nearby road who also heard two gunshots and saw an unidentified man standing over her body. Her murder would later stir speculation relating to the Kennedy assassination.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'New York, New York',
title: 'Dorothy Kilgallen',
html: '<h1>Dorothy Kilgallen</h1><h2>New York City</h2><h2>November 8, 1965</h2><h2>Age: 52</h2><p>Dorothy Kilgallen, 1965, New York City, death certificate reads "acute ethanol and barbiturate intoxication / circumstances undetermined." People who have said publicly that she could have been murdered (perhaps by needle injection after drinking an unknown amount of alcohol) include Larry King, Dominick Dunne, Bob Bach, who booked the mystery guests on Kilgallen''s TV show What''s My Line?, and Manhattan-based magazine writer and novelist Mary Brannum Bringle. Bringle was a colleague of Patricia Bosworth at Screen Stars magazine in 1965 when a strange anonymous phone call reached the magazine''s office and the male phone caller informed Bringle that Dorothy Kilgallen had been murdered.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Penn State University, University Park, PA',
title: 'Betsy Aardsma',
html: '<h1>Betsy Aardsma</h1><h2>Penn State University, University Park, PA</h2><h2>November 28, 1969</h2><h2>Age: 22</h2><p>Betsy Aardsma was a 22-year-old woman from Holland, Michigan, United States and a graduate student at Penn State University, who was stabbed to death in broad daylight in the stacks of Pattee Library on Penn State''s campus on 28 November 1969. She was stabbed a single time through the heart with a single-edged small knife. Approximately one minute later two men came from Betsy''s location and told a desk clerk, "Somebody better help that girl," and then exited the library. The men were never identified. 25–35 minutes later Betsy arrived at a hospital where she was pronounced dead. She had been wearing a red dress, and since there was only a small amount of blood visible, no one immediately realized that she had been stabbed.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Chicago, Illinois',
title: 'Richard Cain',
html: '<h1>Richard Cain</h1><h2>Chicago, Illinois</h2><h2>December 20, 1973</h2><h2>Age: 42</h2><p>On December 20, 1973, Chicago Outfit member Richard Cain was shot to death by masked gunmen in Chicago.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Venice, California',
title: 'Barbara Colby',
html: '<h1>Barbara Colby</h1><h2>Venice, California</h2><h2>July 24, 1975</h2><h2>Age: 36</h2><p>Barbara Colby, an American actress from Venice, California, United States, was shot to death while walking with a colleague to his car on 24 July 1975. She died instantly from her wounds but her colleague was able to describe the shooting to the police before he also died from his wounds. He said the shooting occurred without reason or provocation and said that there were two gunmen whom he did not recognize. There was no attempt at robbery, and the killers and their motivation are still unknown.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Scottsdale, Arizona',
title: 'Bob Crane',
html: '<h1>Bob Crane</h1><h2>Scottsdale, Arizona</h2><h2>June 29, 1978</h2><h2>Age: 49</h2><p>Bob Crane, an American actor best known for his role in Hogan''s Heroes, was discovered bludgeoned to death with a weapon that was never found (but was believed by police to be a camera tripod) at the Winfield Place Apartments in Scottsdale, Ariz., on June 29, 1978. Crane had allegedly called his friend John Henry Carpenter the night before to tell him their friendship was over. Crane was involved in the underground sexual scene and filmed his numerous escapades with the help of Carpenter, who was an audio-visual expert. Police reportedly found blood smears in Carpenter''s car that matched Crane''s blood type, but no charges were filed against Carpenter for more than a decade. When he was charged in 1994, he was acquitted. Carpenter maintained his innocence until his death in 1998, and the case is now officially cold.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Los Angeles, California',
title: 'Raymond Washington',
html: '<h1>Raymond Washington</h1><h2>Los Angeles, California</h2><h2>August 9, 1979</h2><h2>Age: 25</h2><p>Raymond Washington, original founder of the notorious South Central Los Angeles street gang that came to be known as the Crips was murdered on August 9, 1979. Washington was shot dead at the age of 25 when he walked up to a car on the corner of 64th and San Pedro Streets in Los Angeles. At the time of his death, Washington no longer had any real control over the gang he originally founded. He wanted to unite warring gangs in peace and had always opposed guns. Different theories exist on why he was killed and who did it but no one was ever arrested for his murder.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Washington, D.C.',
title: 'Raymond Nels Nelson',
html: '<h1>Raymond Nels Nelson</h1><h2>Washington, D.C.</h2><h2>June 1, 1981</h2><h2>Age: 59</h2><p>Raymond Nels Nelson, Administrative Assistant to Senator Claiborne Pell and former bureau chief of The Providence Journal, Rhode Island. He was found bludgeoned to death with a typewriter in his Washington, D.C. apartment on June 1, 1981</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: '9533 James Madison Highway, Fauquier County, VA',
title: 'William Anthony Kagdis',
html: '<h1>William Anthony Kagdis</h1><h2>9533 James Madison Highway, Fauquier County, VA</h2><h2>August 1, 1982</h2><h2>Age: ?</h2><p>William Anthony Kagdis, On  at approximately 11:50 AM Sheriff''s deputies responded to the Johnson Motel located at 9533 James Madison Highway, Fauquier County, VA, on a report that a guest had been found deceased in his rented room. Upon arrival at the Johnson Motel deputies were directed to room no.17 where they discovered the apparently dead body of a white male lying on one of the beds in the room. The victim was found lying face down in a large pool of blood. The room showed signs of a struggle having taken place. The victim was identified as William Anthony Kagdis, an aeronautical engineer with NASA, who checked into the room at the Johnson Motel the evening before. An autopsy revealed Mr. Kagdis'' death was due to the numerous blunt force injuries he received to his head. Mr. Kagdis had been traveling from his home in Baltimore, MD to Tennessee on business.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Los Angeles, California',
title: 'Peter Ivers',
html: '<h1>Peter Ivers</h1><h2> Los Angeles, California</h2><h2>March 3, 1983</h2><h2>Age: 36</h2><p>Peter Ivers, television host and musician, was found bludgeoned to death in his Los Angeles apartment in 1983. The murder was never solved, although on the basis of new information found in the book In Heaven Everything Is Fine: The Unsolved Life of Peter Ivers and the Lost History of New Wave Theatre (2008) by Josh Frank and Charlie Buckholtz, the Los Angeles Police Department has reopened their investigation into Ivers'' death.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Crofton, Nebraska',
title: 'Tammy Haas',
html: '<h1>Tammy Haas</h1><h2>Crofton, Nebraska</h2><h2>September 17, 1992</h2><h2>Age: 19</h2><p>Tammy Haas, a 19 year old high school student from Yankton, SD went missing after attending a homecoming party on September 17, 1992 with her date, Eric Stukel. Her body was later discovered in a ravine near Crofton, Nebraska not far from the party she attended the night of September 17, 1992. The case eventually went to trial years later and the primary suspect Eric Stukel was acquitted of class III felony manslaughter. It is believed the acquittal was partially due to a Nebraska law requiring the prosecution to prove the victim actually died within Cedar County. Eric Stukel maintains his innocence, and no others have come forward with information that could lead to an arrest.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Warminster, Pennsylvania',
title: 'Seann Campbell and Bryan Benson',
html: '<h1>Seann Campbell and Bryan Benson</h1><h2>Warminster, Pennsylvania</h2><h2>November 10, 1993</h2><h2>Age: 20 (both)</h2><p>On Nov. 10, 1993, Seann Campbell and Bryan Benson, both 20, were stabbed to death at a West Coast Video store in the leafy Philadelphia suburb of Warminster. The boys were attacked as they were closing the shop for the night. They had been stabbed repeatedly in the chest and neck, their bodies discovered the next morning. One major clue, a bloody earring apparently ripped from the ear of an assailant, has never helped police find the killer. $300 was taken from the store, but money was left in the register and the boys'' wallets were not taken. Police believed the boys were killed by one or more persons using a long-bladed knife. Many suspects have been developed by police over the years, including a serial killer who was known to be in the area at the time. There was no evidence of forced entry and no motive has ever been established. This is considered the most notorious unsolved murder in Bucks County, Pennsylvania.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Somerville, Massachusetts',
title: 'Deanna Cremin',
html: '<h1>Deanna Cremin</h1><h2>Somerville, Massachusetts</h2><h2>March 30, 1995</h2><h2>Age: 17</h2><p>Deanna Cremin, a 17-year-old girl from Somerville, Massachusetts, United States, was murdered on March 30, 1995. Her body found behind a senior housing complex. An autopsy revealed she had been strangled. She was last seen alive by her boyfriend who, unlike on other occasions when he would walk her to the door, walked her only half way and she continued on her own toward her house. Her murder remains unsolved.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Minneapolis, Minnesota',
title: 'Anne Barber Dunlap',
html: '<h1>Anne Barber Dunlap</h1><h2>Minneapolis, Minnesota</h2><h2>January 1, 1996</h2><h2>Age: 31</h2><p>Anne Barber Dunlap was found murdered in the trunk of her car in Minneapolis on 1 January 1996. Her husband Brad Dunlap was suspected but never charged, and he sued the insurance company to collect $1 million from a recently established policy. The case is notable because the U.S. District Court ruled that the police had to share with Brad Dunlap any information they shared with the insurance company.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Arlington, Texas',
title: 'Amber Hagerman',
html: '<h1>Amber Hagerman</h1><h2>Arlington, Texas</h2><h2>January 13, 1996</h2><h2>Age: 10</h2><p>Amber Hagerman, victim of an abduction and murder. On 13 January 1996, the 10-year old girl was kidnapped while riding her bike near her grandparents'' home in Arlington, Texas. Four days later, a man walking his dog found her body in a creek bed. An autopsy revealed that her throat had been cut. Although a $75,000 reward was offered for information leading to Hagerman''s killer, the perpetrator was never found. Her murder would later inspire the creation of the AMBER Alert system.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Las Vegas, Nevada',
title: 'Tupac Shakur',
html: '<h1>Tupac Shakur</h1><h2>Las Vegas, Nevada</h2><h2>September 7, 1996</h2><h2>Age: 25</h2><p>Tupac Shakur, a top-selling American Rapper who was shot four times in a drive-by shooting on 7 September 1996, in Las Vegas, Nevada, United States. He died six days later of respiratory failure and cardiac arrest at the University Medical Center.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Boulder, Colorado',
title: 'Jon Benét Ramsey',
html: '<h1>Jon Benét Ramsey</h1><h2>Boulder, Colorado</h2><h2>December 26, 1996</h2><h2>Age: 6</h2><p>Jon Benét Ramsey, a six-year-old American girl who had competed in child beauty pageants, was made famous by her Christmastime murder and the subsequent media coverage. She was found dead in the basement of her parents'' home in Boulder, Colorado, on December 26, 1996, nearly eight hours after she was reported missing. The official cause of death was asphyxia due to strangulation associated with craniocerebral trauma. After several grand jury hearings, the case is still unsolved. Her parents were suspects, but authorities eventually confirmed that the couple had been cleared of any involvement.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Los Angeles, California',
title: 'The Notorious B.I.G.',
html: '<h1>The Notorious B.I.G.</h1><h2>Los Angeles, California</h2><h2>March 9, 1997</h2><h2>Age: 24</h2><p>The Notorious B.I.G., a famous Brooklyn rapper killed by an unknown assailant in a drive-by shooting on 9 March 1997, in Los Angeles, California, United States. Even though a composite sketch of the perpetrator was made, the case is still unsolved.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: '246 Church Street, New Haven, CT 06520',
title: 'Suzanne Jovin',
html: '<h1>Suzanne Jovin</h1><h2>Yale Campus</h2><h2>December 4, 1998</h2><h2>Age: 21</h2><p>Suzanne Jovin, a 21-year-old senior at Yale University, was found stabbed to death on December 4, 1998 on the campus of Yale. Allegations that her thesis advisor was a suspect led to the end of his career at Yale, but the crime remains unsolved.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Scarborough, Maine',
title: 'Ashley Ouellette',
html: '<h1>Ashley Ouellette</h1><h2>Scarborough, Maine</h2><h2>February 10, 1999</h2><h2>Age: 15</h2><p>Ashley Ouellette, a fifteen-year-old female from Saco, Maine, was found lying in the middle of Pine Point Road in Scarborough, Maine, by passing motorists on 10 February 1999 at 3:57am. Ouellette was last seen alive at approximately 2:00am at Earl Sanborn Jr. and Muriel Sanborn residence in Saco. She was allowed to spend the night there, however, by morning Ashley had disappeared from the residence. Ouellette was not seen again until found in the road.</p>'
});


$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Harlem, New York',
title: 'Big L',
html: '<h1>Big L</h1><h2>Harlem, New York</h2><h2>February 15, 1999</h2><h2>Age: 24</h2><p>Big L, a Harlem rapper, was shot multiple times in the head and chest near his Harlem home on February 15, 1999.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'St. Charles County, Missouri',
title: 'Ricky McCormick',
html: '<h1>Ricky McCormick</h1><h2>St. Charles County, Missouri</h2><h2>June 30, 1999</h2><h2>Age: 41</h2><p>Ricky McCormick whose body was found in a field by sheriff''s officers in St. Charles County, Missouri, on June 30, 1999. The only clues to the mystery are two notes in his pockets, apparently written in a complex cipher.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: '600 James St, Syracuse, NY',
title: 'Jill-Lyn Euto',
html: '<h1>Jill-Lyn Euto</h1><h2>Syracuse, NY</h2><h2>January 28,2001</h2><h2>Age: 18</h2><p>Jill-Lyn Euto, an 18 year old student, was found stabbed to death in her sixth-floor apartment at 600 James St, Syracuse, NY on 28 January 2001. No arrests have been made.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Seattle, Washington',
title: 'Thomas C. Wales',
html: '<h1>Thomas C. Wales</h1><h2>Seattle, Washington</h2><h2>October 11, 2001</h2><h2>Age: 49</h2><p>Thomas C. Wales (b:1952) was an American federal prosecutor and gun control advocate. On October 11, 2001, he was killed by a bullet fired through the window of his basement home-office in Seattle, Washington. No suspects have been charged, and the investigation continues.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Carlsbad, NM',
title: 'Sasha Marie Hedgecock',
html: '<h1>Sasha Marie Hedgecock</h1><h2>Carlsbad, NM</h2><h2>December 25, 2002</h2><h2>Age: 21</h2><p>Sasha Marie Hedgecock (b:1981) Shasha was last known to have visited a local convenience store Allsup''s early in the morning on December 25, 2002, where she was abducted and shot 7 times in the head and abdomen. As of 2014 this murder remains one amongst dozens of unsolved murders in over nearly 50 years in Carlsbad, NM giving the city a reputation as the easiest place to commit murder and get away with it. The city has also made the list of cities with the largest unsolved murders per capita.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'San Francisco, California',
title: 'Evelyn Hernandez and probably others',
html: '<h1>Evelyn Hernandez and probably others</h1><h2>San Francisco, California</h2><h2>July 24, 2002</h2><h2>Age: 24</h2><p>Evelyn Hernandez, 24, and her 5-year-old son Alex, last heard from on 1 May 2002 at her residence in San Francisco, California. Her wallet was found several days later, in South San Francisco. Hernandez was nine months pregnant at the time and on 24 July 2002 her torso was found floating in San Francisco Bay. Her unborn child and her son Alex have not been found. The case was profiled twice on America''s Most Wanted during the summer of 2003.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Bushwick, Brooklyn, New York',
title: 'Rashawn Brazell',
html: '<h1>Rashawn Brazell</h1><h2>Bushwick, Brooklyn, New York</h2><h2>February 14, 2005</h2><h2>Age: 19</h2><p>Rashawn Brazell, disappeared after leaving his home in Bushwick, Brooklyn, New York, United States, on the morning of 14 February 2005. His dismembered body parts were later found in garbage bags. America''s Most Wanted profiled the case five times, most recently in 2008.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Pompano Beach, Florida',
title: 'Chris Reyka',
html: '<h1>Chris Reyka</h1><h2>Pompano Beach, Florida</h2><h2>August 10, 2007</h2><h2>Age: 51</h2><p>Sergeant Chris Reyka. On August 10, 2007, Sergeant Chris Reyka of the Broward County Sheriff''s Office was shot and killed while investigating a report of suspicious vehicles in a Walgreen''s parking lot in Pompano Beach. At some point during the stop one of the suspects opened fire on Sergeant Reyke, killing him. The suspect''s vehicle was captured on a security camera fleeing the scene, but no arrests have been made.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Washington, D.C.',
title: 'Robert Wone',
html: '<h1>Robert Wone</h1><h2>Washington, D.C.</h2><h2>August, 2006</h2><h2>Age: 32</h2><p>Robert Wone, age 32, was murdered on August 2, 2006, in his friend''s Washington, D.C., apartment. He was &qt;restrained, incapacitated, and sexually assaulted&qt; prior to his death. The only individuals present in the apartment at the time were its three residents, all friends of Wone. They have denied involvement and insisted that an intruder committed the crime. Authorities claim that there was no evidence of a break-in: the apartment appeared to be washed and cleaned, the three residents appeared freshly showered, and the evidence was not consistent with the residents'' accounts. In addition, the residents tampered with the crime scene, waited an inordinate amount of time to call 911, and exhibited strange behavior when paramedics and police arrived. Authorities believe that either some or all of the three house-mates murdered Wone and engaged in a cover-up.</p>'
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
address: 'Bluegrass Parkway near Bardstown, Kentucky',
title: 'Jason Ellis',
html: '<h1>Jason Ellis</h1><h2>Bluegrass Parkway near Bardstown, Kentucky</h2><h2>May 25, 2013</h2><h2>Age: 35</h2><p>Police Officer Jason Ellis, 35. Shot and killed while returning home from work on the Bluegrass Parkway near Bardstown, Kentucky in the early morning hours of May 25, 2013. Debris was placed in the road and an assailant killed Officer Ellis with a shotgun from a nearby hill as he exited his marked patrol car to clear the debris. No suspects have been identified</p>'
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have other "all-in-one" HTML files that run just fine as html files, but this one is balking.

Comment: check your browser console

Comment: you should escape quotes, not double quotes in strings. This `\' `instead of `''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

**1)** In `HTML` field of `createMaker` you are saying `''s` for apostrophe, but there you should escape the quote `\'s`. I did a replace all `''` with `\'` and that problem solved.

**2)** In the last of your `script` you are forgetting `});`, just add this it should work.

I don't had `gomap.js` so it was giving error `undefined is not a function` so make sure `gomap.js` is there.